# How can I create shadow on Raphael objects and drag?

Tags: raphael, draggable, shadow

I know that there are ways to create a shadow on `Raphael` object:

1. By creating **glow()** and changing its `offsetx` and `offsety`
2. Also there is a library to do that

My issue is that I need to drag the shadow with the object. So far I can get object moving, but shadow will not move. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to your question **"Any hints?"**

Well do the following:

1. Create a clone and make it `glow`
2. `Hide` your new object so that only glow will apeare
3. Adjust the coords of `glow`
4. Then create a `Raphael SET` and add those two objects to it
5. Now you can apply drag on your SET

Good luck